# How to remove an entry from the Eclipse ColorRegistry?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface

I use the Eclipse [ColorRegistry](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fresource%2FColorRegistry.html) to manage user-generated colors in an RCP application.

Because the colors and keys are user-generated, there is also the possibility for the user to change the color that is associated with a key or to remove the key / color combination entirely. However, the `ColorRegistry`class only has a `put` method to write or replace a color, but no remove method.

Is there a way to remove a color from the registry?

The only workaround I came up with would be to replace the color with a default value, but I would prefer a clean solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no there is no way to remove an entry from the `ColorRegistry`.

You could use a `Map` or similar custom data structure instead to store named colors. If it is likely that many names point to the same color, you may want to use `ColorDescriptors` or `RGB`s and a `ResourceManager` as the backing color store to avoid creating duplicate colors.